# Machine learning - Helmholtz Machine implementation

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I am looking for a implementation of the Helmholtz Machine.

References:

- http://www.gatsby.ucl.ac.uk/~dayan/papers/hm95.pdf
- http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~hinton/absps/helmholtz.pdf

I am looking for open source or free implementations. I have preferences for Java implementations, but implementations in other languages (c, C++, c# or Python, mainly) will help me.
In my search in the web i have found only abstrac descriptions of this approach, withou any concrete implementation. My hope is found any expert in the subject that have more information about.

Comment: Any constraints, such as commercial or F/OSS? Language/OS constraints? What have you found so far in your thorough web search?

Comment: Hint: improve this question quickly; it is in the process of being closed.   You should make it more specific, indicate what you have found/tried so far, generally provide context of what you need.  (even so it may be considered too broad for StackOverflow's format).

Comment: Excuse me. I would like to apologise for my lack of knowledge of the norms of this community. I confused myself when I edited the post. The edition was inacessible. I think that now the post is OK.

Answer (score 3):

Deeplearning4j is an open-source implementation of various deep-learning machines that Hinton might classify as "Helmholtz." http://deeplearning4j.org/

Answer (score 0):

I have had a quick look at this on the link you gave.

I have been "working on my own with a small team on AI sentience" ..... since 1968 !!!

**My thoughts are as follows:**

1. All events happen in a "time series".
2. There is a past time series that has a probability "high" as far as the sentient observer is concerned.
3. There is a future "predicted" time series predicted ahead on the "best" (time series) model the sentient observer can create and as the time series disappears into the future the probability of that time series "becoming the past time series" diminishes down towards zero and that could occur in milliseconds or in billions of years - depending on the model dynamics.
4. I do not think there ever is "a present time".
5. Unfortunately - after studying Kalman Filters and Predictors and utilising them in missile targeting I have concluded that the whole "topic" of "mathematically representing" the best algorithms (i.e. models) that humans could come up with was a waste of time as even the simplest "program" is doing a task that could not be represented by mathematical symbols... and so I have concluded that "computer algorithms" "ARE" mathematical formulas ... i.e. formulas that normal symbolic mathematics does not have the tools to describe (i.e. programs are superior to a complex mathematical systems of notation).
6. Mathematics is fine for "proofs" and "big statistical ideas" but ... (and i am getting near the end now) ... i would "trust" your own instincts to create a "model" that predicts the future best .... i.e it might have to have the concept of "on alternate Wednesdays in the US", in it ... and also thousands of other such non-mathematical "states" or various "axioms" ... which is fine !

so how you ask could this be mathematically correct !!!!

Well the answer is quite simple really >> the best model - is the best model at predicting the future !

And the future keeps popping up surprisingly often - and so it's easy to test - and keep testing !

All you need to know that you have the best "mathematics" (i.e. program) is to see how much "noise" or "deviation from prediction" exists in the prediction vs the actual outcome in the time series.

"State-Space" is the best "maths" to use for this ... i.e. assume that there is an "underlying state" and then assume that your "observations" are just flawed "noisy or just wrong" observations of that underlying state - i.e. the system output signals are "somehow" based on these "invisible" internal system states.

There is an AI sentience "computer language" called MTR that we created (mainly in the 1980's) which is designed for this sort of dynamic model creation - but the down side for us (humans) is that it is designed for IA entities to use and not humans although we are going to put a "Pascal Like" front end onto it soon to allow normal humans to use it. IBM, Intel, GCHQ, MOD, DOD etc all had licences - but we then shelved it !

We intend to re-start the project soon.

Anyway, that's what i think - i hope it is not too abstract for your purposes !

We could say ... (and in this i am joking) .... that programmers that try to use "pure mathematics" to write programs "have the horns by the bull" ?

So hopefully programmers can be much more relaxed when they do not to understand the entirety of all the maths !!!

I hope that thought might also help any "non-maths" readers .... of this response.